# No Backtrace on request specs with Rspec

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have a request spec like this

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'People API' do

  describe 'GET /api/v1/people/lookup.json?phone_number=PHONE_NUMBER', :wip do
    it 'returns a 200 status code' do
      auth_get '/api/v1/people/lookup.json', phone_number: '91900199'
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

and if the specs fail for some reason I just get a 500 status code in the response, and that's it, so I have to check the `log/test.log` file to get to know what went wrong, that is pretty annoying.

**Why rspec is not showing the backtrace like in other types of specs?**

Here is how I run my specs, notice that I include the -b option

```
$ rspec -b -t wip -f documentation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Run options: include {:wip=>true}

People API
  GET /api/v1/people/lookup.json?phone_number=PHONE_NUMBER
    returns a 200 status code

Failures:

  1) People API GET /api/v1/people/lookup.json?phone_number=PHONE_NUMBER with an empty phone number returns a empty response
     Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(200)

       expected: 200
            got: 500

       (compared using ==)
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.1/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:30:in `fail_with'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.1/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:35:in `handle_failure'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.1/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.1/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:54:in `to'
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/people_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `block in run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:294:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `call'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:432:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:303:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:145:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:494:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `map'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:457:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `block in run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `map'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `block in run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `map'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `map'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:54:in `report'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /Users/fespinoza/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.46863 seconds (files took 3.59 seconds to load)
1 examples, 1 failures
```

but it does not contain the real reason of the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Your request specs interact with your full stack, including middleware. When an error occurs inside one of your controller methods, it is caught higher up the stack so that a 500 error can be returned to the client. This is what you are seeing in the assertion failure.

You might be able to write your own middleware for testing purposes which prints errors to `stderr` if you really want this.